# <video> doesn't call ended event

Tags: javascript, html, web, iframe

How to detect if context window of iframe has a video on the page?

```
window.onload = function () {
    var pages = '@ViewBag.pages';
    var p = JSON.parse(pages.replace(/(&quot\;)/g, "\""));
    var i = 0;
    var mi = p.length - 1;
    var interval;
    console.log("frame is loaded");
    var video = $(document).find("iframe").contents().find("video");
    if (video.length == 1) {
        console.log(0); 
        clearInterval(interval);
        video.on('ended', function () {
            document.getElementById('slider').src = src;
        });
    }
    else {  console.log(5);
         interval = setInterval(function () {
            i++;
            if (i > mi) { i = 0 }
            var src = p[i];
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: src,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function () {
                    document.getElementById('slider').src = src;
                }
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong and why the page with video loops again and again without 'onended' event?

Comment: you can find with jquery as `jQuery(document).find("iframe").contents().find("video")`

Comment: so if it finds a video how to call an event?

Comment: what you want to do if find video tag

Comment: if the page in frame has a video tag -> wait until it ends and go to next slide

Comment: use <video onended="myFunction()"> and do what you want there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HTML5.
Here is an example -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var videos = $(document).find("iframe").contents().find("video");
    $(videos).each(function(){
        $(this).on('ended', function(){
            console.log('Video has ended!');
            // Execute you function to move next slides
        });
    });
});
```